# Wait for Message on_member_join using checks (discord.py) | SOLVED

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to wait for a private message that was sent only by the member. I am trying to use the `check` parameter for the `client.wait_for()` method but I can not seem to get it. I tried putting the check as the `response.author` but will not work since I just assigned `response`. Also I am executing this when a member joins using `on_member_join` which takes in a `member` argument (like this `async def on_member_join(member)`. Anyone know how to properly do this? Any answers would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code for this:

```
    await member.send('What is your student number? ')
    response = await client.wait_for('message')
    student_number = response.content
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding a check function to `wait_for`, that check function will get the received message as an argument. This means that it will check every single message the bot gets, pass all of them to your check function, and wait until one of them makes the check return `True`.

```
@client.event()
async def on_member_join(member):
    def check(message):
        return message.author.id == member.id and message.guild is None

    await member.send('What is your student number?')
    response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    student_number = response.content
```

Note how my example also makes sure the `guild` is `None`, as you explicitly mentioned waiting for a private message.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Thanks to you I now understand how checks work.